# css is auto-commenting php code?

Tags: php, css, comments

I have an issue with CSS..

By using the following code:

```
<div class="divisor">
<p>
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['invalid'])) { echo 'test'; } ?>
</p>
</div>
```

The result on the generated page in browser is the following:

```
<!--?php if (isset($_SESSION['invalid'])) { echo 'test'; } ?-->
```

Practically, the browser is auto-commenting out my php code, with the result of skipping the whole code from executing it.

What could be the issue?

the CSS code I only defined some margins with:

```
.divisor p {
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely not the browser, because the page delivered to the browser doesn't contain any more PHP tags. (Given that PHP is active on the server.) I would guess that you're running the PHP file through some type of filter or template engine which messes on the PHP tags instead of executing their code.

Comment: Make sure your page is saved as .php

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with CSS; your PHP code shouldn't ever reach the browser in the first place.

Make sure you have PHP installed and your web server is set up to interpret PHP scripts. Right now, it appears to be treating them as HTML.

Note that you must access this page through a server; it's not enough just to open a file on your local machine in a browser.

Comment: i forgot to save the page as .php and i runned it as .html .. *facepalm*